# How to keep a tensorflow session running in memory with django

Tags: django, tensorflow

I have an object detection model built with tensorflow and integrated with a Django project. What currently happens is that whenever a request comes to the Django API, a tf session is created and is closed after the detection is done. Is it possible to start the Django server and a tensorflow session with the required inference graphs to reduce object detection time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would consist in abstracting the logic to run inference using a session in module. In this module, the session, and the graph would be defined once as global variable, and would be transparently accessed by your views, or whatever, using interfaces like a function `run_inference`.

If you need more fine control over the lifecycle of the graph and/or session you could consider adding functions like `reload_graph` etc... or implement that within your module, for example using a class dedicated to managing the lifecycle of the tensorflow objects, and running inference.

This looks to me like the best solution. This way you will also be able to have a more robust workflow, and have more control in case for example you want to use multithreading and want more safety with respect to how the inference code is run.

Comment: this is not the best solution, a long time ago graph and session were no longer needed, even the global variables.
if you adhere to the MLOPS practice it is best to leave as many pre and post processes pre loaded and then only generate the inference when a request arrives to your api. 

https://github.com/Nouvellie/django-mlops-docker/blob/main/src/main/apps/mlops/utils/model_loader.py 

tried many ways, session/graphs, tf, and tflite, 
and by far, by far, the best is tflite.
it's the most efficient, and with gunicorn/nginx you can easily make parallel calls, without any problems

Answer (score 0):

As I commented to the previous solution suggestion, graph/session stopped being the optimal solution a long time ago.
I recommend you to start using mlops, and leave everything preloaded as much as you can, so that when you call the api, django only takes care of generating the predict.
I leave you here my project, I have several with ML/Django/Tflite

If you have any doubt don't hesitate to ask me.

Link to my project: https://github.com/Nouvellie/django-mlops-docker/blob/main/src/main/apps/mlops/utils/model_loader.py